# Likelihood Ratio Test for the Normal Distribution with unknown mean

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, hypothesis-testing

Let $(X_{1},...,X_{n})$ a $n$ sample of the law $N( \mu, \sigma^{2})$.
We assumed we don't know $\mu$ and $\sigma^{2}$.

Let $\mu_{0} \in \mathbb{R}$.

> Show that the Likelihood-ratio test for $\mu = \mu_{0}$ against $\mu
>  \ne \mu_{0}$ is function of  $$ 1 + \frac{(\bar{X_{n}} - \mu_{0}
>  )^{2}}{\sigma_{n}^{2}} $$ with $\sigma_{n}^{2}  = \sum_{i=1}^{n}
>  \frac{(X_{i} - \bar{X_{n}})^{2}}{n}$

EDIT : I showed that the Likelihood-ratio test is
$$
\exp\left( \frac{n}{2 s_{n}^{2}(X)} (\bar{X_{n}} - \mu_{0} ) \right)
$$ 
with $s_{n}^{2}(X) = \sum_{i=1}^n\frac{(X_i-\mu_0)^2}{n}$
But I don't know how to conclude.

Thanks and regards.

Comment: I think the equation for the variance is wrong. What does $>$ do there?

Comment: Oh the > is just to make the text highlighted. Let me edit. Oh and yes thank you it was a copy error.

Comment: also the value of the test is $exp(-\frac{n}{2 \sigma ^2}(\bar{X}-\mu_0)^2)$

Comment: I found this computing $ \frac{\sup_{H_{1}}}{\sup_{H_{0}}}$. Oh okay. But it doesn't change my question.

Comment: It is $ \frac{\sup_{H_0}}{\sup_{H_1}}$

Comment: That's why we didn't find the same result. Anyway it doesn't change my question.

Comment: The likelihood ratio test statistic is usually defined as $\Lambda=\frac{\sup_{H_0}L(\theta)}{\sup_{H_0\cup H_1}L(\theta)}$ where $L$ is the likelihood and $\theta$ is the parameter of interest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$L_{H_0} = (2\pi\sigma^2)^{-\frac{n}{2}}exp(-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-\mu_0)^2)$

$supL_{H_1} = (2\pi\sigma^2)^{-\frac{n}{2}}exp(-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-\bar{X})^2)$ ($\bar{X}$ is the maximum likelihood estimate for $\mu$ if $\mu$ is unknown).

The problem is that you are treating $\sigma^2$ as given parameter instead of unknown. If you maximize the likelihood wrt $\sigma^2$ for ${H_0}$ you will obtain that the maximum likelihood estimate  for $\sigma^2$ is $\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{(X_i-\mu_0)^2}{n}$ (analogously for ${H_1}$ it is $\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{(X_i-\bar{X})^2}{n}$).

After plugging in the estimate for $\sigma^2$ you will obtain:

$\sup L_{H_0} = (2\pi\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{(X_i-\mu_0)^2}{n})^{-\frac{n}{2}}exp\Bigg(-\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-\mu_0)^2}{2{\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{(X_i-\mu_0)^2}{n}}}\Bigg)=\big(\frac{2\pi}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-\mu_0)^2)^{-\frac{n}{2}}exp(-\frac{n}{2})$

and $\sup L_{H_1} = (2\pi\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{(X_i-\bar{X})^2}{n})^{-\frac{n}{2}}exp\Bigg(-\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-\bar{X}^2)}{2{\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{(X_i-\bar{X})^2}{n}}}\Bigg) =\big(\frac{2\pi}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-\bar{X})^2)^{-\frac{n}{2}}exp(-\frac{n}{2})$.

I.e. $\Lambda = \Bigg(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-\mu_0)^2}{\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-\bar{X})^2}\Bigg)^{-\frac{n}{2}}$.

$\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-\mu_0)^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n((X_i-\bar{X})+(\bar{X}-\mu_0))^2 =  \sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-\bar{X})^2+n(\bar{X}-\mu_0)^2$.

Plugging back into the equation for $\Lambda$ we obtain: $\Lambda = \Bigg(1+\frac{n(\bar{X}-\mu_0)^2}{\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-\bar{X})^2}\Bigg)^{-\frac{n}{2}}$.

Comment: why $exp(-\frac{n}{2})$ ? I though of $\exp\left( \frac{-\| X-\mu_{0} \|)^{2}}{2(\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{(X_i-\mu_0)^2}{n})}  \right)$ for $H_{0}$

Comment: @CechMS I hav edited my post to make it clearer.

Comment: @ I think $L_{H_{0}}$ still need a update.

Comment: My course just tell me that $\frac{\sup_{\Theta_{1}} L(\theta)}{\sup_{\Theta_{0}}L(\theta)}$. So I just tried to apply the formula for $\Theta_{0} = \{ \mu_{0} \}$.
But it doesn't really match with the set of parameters $ \mathbb{R} \times ]0;+\infty[$. So if I try now to consider $\Theta_{0} =  \{ \mu_{0} \} \times  ]0;+\infty[$ and $\Theta_{1} = \mathbb{R}- \{ \mu_{0} \} \times  ]0;+\infty[$. It could be more coherent.

Comment: @CechMS I dont think I can make it more clearer than this.

Comment: Okay I got it ! But you used the equality :
$$
\sup_{x \in X} \sup_{y \in X} f(x,y) = \sup_{(x,y)\in X \times Y} f(x,y)
$$
and it's not always true. So we must justify.

Comment: @CechMS The density of the normal distributions is a smooth, infinitely differentiable function over the entire $\mathbb{R \times R_+}$, I took the first order conditions for both parameters. This is perfectly legal in this case.